# How to build FLTK to using with Netbeans (Windows)

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin, fltk

How to build FLTK to using with Netbeans (Windows), i have tried but not success. Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What problem did you run into, and what compiler? I'll assume you're using GCC and the Cygwin tools?

From [FLTK's own site](http://www.fltk.org/documentation.php/doc-1.1/intro.html#Building%20%FLTK%20Under%20Microsoft%20Windows)

> There are three ways to build FLTK
> under Microsoft Windows. The first is
> to use the Visual C++ 5.0 project
> files under the "visualc" directory.
> Just open (or double-click on) the
> "fltk.dsw" file to get the whole
> shebang.
>
> The second method is to use the
> configure script included with the
> FLTK software; this has only been
> tested with the CygWin tools:
>
> sh configure --prefix=C:/FLTK
>
> make

Comment: First, I copy fltk to C:/FLTK. Then, I go to C:/cygwin/cygwin.bat -> type sh configure --prefix=C:/FLTK => Sh: configure : No such file or directory

Comment: Did you change your directory to the directory where you copied the FLTK source code to? (`/cygdrive/c/FLTK` it seems like) If you haven't done that there will be no `configure` file since it's with the source.

Comment: My advice - use MinGW+SYS with installed autotools, and the rest. With it you can build FLTK nicely on Windows using typical `./configure --prefix=$HOME/bin && make && make install` (or similar)